# Layout Mess up when changed to locale to urdu language

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a running application and I have implemented the search view in the action bar of the app. And that's all is working fine.

I have database in which things are saved in Urdu language so want to give relaxation to user that He/she may search also in Urdu.

So when I change My locale to urdu from Android Os language and keyboard setting , My whole Layout gets mess up.

It looks like Locale has effect on the layout too. I know its about the configuration changes. but How to deal with it . Please share some ideas. Its not working and I do not want my layout to get change when locale is changed.

> Edit one :  THis is what happen

**Before changing locale every thing is perfect in listview**

[image]

**After changing locale list view mess up** 
[image]

> **EDIT 2:** Note: this is the xml I am using in app. The upper given
>   images are just for example.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"

    >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl_textviews"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContentNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_text_size"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tv_name_padding_left"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/tv_name_padding_right"
            android:text="flash"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_text_size"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvContentNum"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvContentNum"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvContentNum"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/rl_textviews"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvUrduName"
            android:text="Flas"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_frame"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tv_urdu_name_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tv_urdu_name_margin_top"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_text_size"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_frame"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/framelayout_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/framelayout_margin_right">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_contents"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/iv_content_margin_top"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/iv_content_margin_right"
            android:src="@drawable/list_next_icon"
            />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help. Any source code would be appreciated

Comment: It would be great if you provide the screenshots also.

Comment: let me give you idea ...........attaching the diagram

Comment: @dex its  included

Comment: what locale are you changing to ?

Comment: show me code you are using to chnage the locale

Comment: I am not changing it from code I am changing it from the system. to check how it would look when user change his locale to urdu to use urdu keyboard

Comment: Can you also share you row view xml file ?

Comment: how it is going to help you

Comment: it is just for the example ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: I can share the actual xml file ,,,,

Comment: @dex xml is shared. See the edit part 2

Comment: why don't you use android:layoutDirection  property to disable RTL effect and avoid shifting of rows

Comment: @dex can you please show me How to do this

Comment: use this flag in the parent layout android:layoutDirection = "false"